# Why don't I see the workflow module in Powershell 3.0 on Windows 7?

Tags: powershell, windows-7, workflow

I recently installed Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64 on my Windows 7 machine so that I can use Powershell 3.0. After I run the update, and launch a Powershell window, it definitely is version 3. However, it doesn't appear that the Workflow stuff has been installed. Running Get-Module -ListAvailable shows no workflow stuff:

```
ModuleType Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- ----                                ----------------
Manifest   BitsTransfer                        {Add-BitsFile, Remove-BitsTransfer, Complete-BitsTransfer, Get-BitsTr...
Manifest   CimCmdlets                          {Get-CimAssociatedInstance, Get-CimClass, Get-CimInstance, Get-CimSes...
Script     ISE                                 {New-IseSnippet, Import-IseSnippet, Get-IseSnippet}
Manifest   Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics    {Get-WinEvent, Get-Counter, Import-Counter, Export-Counter...}
Manifest   Microsoft.PowerShell.Host           {Start-Transcript, Stop-Transcript}
Manifest   Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Content, Clear-Content, Clear-ItemProperty, Join-Path...}
Manifest   Microsoft.PowerShell.Security       {Get-Acl, Set-Acl, Get-PfxCertificate, Get-Credential...}
Manifest   Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Format-List, Format-Custom, Format-Table, Format-Wide...}
Manifest   Microsoft.WSMan.Management          {Disable-WSManCredSSP, Enable-WSManCredSSP, Get-WSManCredSSP, Set-WSM...
Script     PSDiagnostics                       {Disable-PSTrace, Disable-PSWSManCombinedTrace, Disable-WSManTrace, E...
Binary     PSScheduledJob                      {New-JobTrigger, Add-JobTrigger, Remove-JobTrigger, Get-JobTrigger...}
Manifest   TroubleshootingPack                 {Get-TroubleshootingPack, Invoke-TroubleshootingPack}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're running a 64-bit PowerShell console if you're running on 64-bit Windows 7.  The PSWorkflow module is not available in the x86 PowerShell console.